# Advantages of using MTOM with XOP

Tags: java, web-services, soap, weblogic, mtom

I wonder what are the main benefits of using a WS with MTOM. (without streaming the attachment)

I understand that the payload will not contain the binary data which will be part of MIME

"When you use MTOM/XOP to optimize a SOAP message, the XOP processing serializes it into a MIME Multipart/Related message. The XOP processing extracts the base64Binary data from the SOAP message and packages it as separate binary attachments within the MIME message, in a similar manner to e-mail attachments"

SO the payload will probably smaller (but not much ) then base64 format

BUT without using streaming attachment i see little advantage... the payload will end up in memory anyway as soap is deserialized.

So if the SOAP has to contain a big PDF file which i have to store it ... with pure MTOM there will be not so much benefit if i will not use streaming attachment cause multiple users in the same time might crash the server with OOME...

Am i wrong ?

Comment: Cris: did you solve this? Could you please post the findings/conclusion?

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons for using MTOM instead:

- MTOM has good interoperability. The MTOM is a **W3C recommendation**,
  that is endorsed by Microsoft, IBM, Oracle, and so on.
- MTOM attachments can be processed by the Web services functionalities
  as needed. The temporary Base64 representation of the attachments
  allows the SOAP engine to use them for generating a message signature,
  performing encryption, and so on.
- MTOM has no impact on development. There is no special API for handling the SOAP attachments.

Comment: These are indeed general benefits....Is streaming of the attachments done automatically...?

Comment: I use MTOM but for my case if there is no streaming ...there is no real benefit (i have large pdfs)

Comment: The content type of the response must be `multipart/related` The atachment `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: Done that ....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14522489/ws-download-operation-with-mtom ..here is in more detail the problem i face.Thanks

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13734/mtom.htm on streaming SOAP attachments on the server side example

Comment: believe i know them by heart :) that doc was the starting point but do not answer my problem. Is there a possibility to fully stream the binary content via webservice .I need to figure out a datasource for DataHandler in order to alow me to stream from DB to client

Comment: Have you see http://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/metro-and-jaxb/dynamically-configure-streamingattachment-properties?